# Is O_NOATIME safe to ignore?

Tags: filesystem, files

I am designing a filesystem to be implemented in FUSE. I have a question regarding what is allowed and best practice. There are 2 scenarios:

- User process calls `open(..., O_NOATIME).` Filesystem updates atime
  anyway. **Is this safe?**
- User process calls `open(...)` without `O_NOATIME.` Filesystem
  forgets to update atime. **Is this safe?**

Assume that new atime is written to disk only if also other important attributes have changed. Therefore sometimes an update may follow, sometimes not.

Filesystem would have no mount parameters for changing behaviour. Behaviour described above would be default and mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

From `man 2 open`:

```
O_NOATIME (since Linux 2.6.8)
       Do  not update the file last access time (st_atime in the inode)
       when the file is read(2).  This flag  is  intended  for  use  by
       indexing  or  backup  programs,  where its use can significantly
       reduce the amount of disk activity.  This flag may not be effec‐
       tive  on  all filesystems.  One example is NFS, where the server
       maintains the access time.
```

So the flag makes no guarantees that it will be respected and is explicitly called out as only really being important for reducing disk activity.

Sounds like you will be fine for scenario 1 where you update it anyway.

As for scenario 2, you should still be fine.  Filesystems can be mounted with a `noatime` flag that prevents atime from being updated.  So user code cannot assume that it absolutely will be updated.

Comment: There is not much remaining software that requires ATIME, but it does exist.  Mutt is (was? is it still?) an example as it used it to determine what hadn't been viewed before.  As long as it's documented adequately then it's fair for a given filesystem not to support a feature IMHO.